# Ubuntu + Windows 8.1 in a SSD

Tags: windows, ssd

I have a 120Gb SSD and I want to install Ubuntu as my main OS and use Windows just for gaming. My question is: Is this partition table that I'm creating correct?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQrZq.jpg

sda1 = 20Gb (Ubuntu OS) sda5 = 5Gb (swap) sda6 = 88Gb (to install Windows ... forget the ext4, I already corrected that after this hehe) free space = 7Gb, as I saw that we need to leave some free space in the end of the SSD to maintain it healthy.

Is all this scheme correct? Do I really need 5gb SWAP area even with 8Gb DD3 memory in my laptop?

Thanks for the help! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure swap space is supposed to reflect how much RAM you have, but it shouldn't be too important.
The drive layout looks fine, but you'll want to format it that way and then install Windows before installing Ubuntu. Do this by using Gparted on the LiveCD. If you install Ubuntu first, Windows will overwrite or take away control from Ubuntu's boot files, making Windows the only one to boot.